# bootstrap tabs inside accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the tabs inside accordion to make a categories menu.
When the user click on a category he gets list of subcategories and when they click on the subcategory they gets list with all the products.
I managed to write the jQuery but I'm getting error in the console:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'tab' of undefined`

```
<div class="container container-pad">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <ul class="list-group category" role="tablist">
          <li class="list-group-item">
            <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse"  href="#collapseOne">
              categories 1
            </a>
          </li>
          <ul id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <li class="list-group-item" role="presentation">
              <a href="#category1" aria-controls="category1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">category 1<span class="badge">1</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="list-group-item" role="presentation">
              <a href="#category2" aria-controls="category2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">category 2<span class="badge">2</span></a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <li class="list-group-item">
            <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse"  href="#collapseTwo">
              categories 2
            </a>
          </li>
          <ul id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <li class="list-group-item" role="presentation">
              <a href="#category3" aria-controls="category3" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">category 3<span class="badge">3</span></a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <li class="list-group-item">
            <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse"  href="#collapseThree">
              categories 3
            </a>
          </li>
          <ul id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <li class="list-group-item" role="presentation">
              <a href="#category4" aria-controls="category4" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">category 4<span class="badge">4</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="list-group-item" role="presentation">
              <a href="#category5" aria-controls="category5" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">category 5<span class="badge">5</span></a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-9">
        <div class="tab-content">
          <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="category1">
            <ul class="list-group products">
             <li class="list-group-item">
               product 1
             </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="category2">
            <ul class="list-group products">
              <li class="list-group-item">
                product 2
              </li>
              <li class="list-group-item">
               product 3
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="category3">
            <ul class="list-group products">
              <li class="list-group-item">
                product 4
              </li>
              <li class="list-group-item">
               product 5
              </li>
              <li class="list-group-item">
                product 6
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="category4">
            <ul class="list-group products">
              <li class="list-group-item">
                product 7
              </li>
              <li class="list-group-item">
                product 8
              </li>
              <li class="list-group-item">
                product 9
              </li>
              <li class="list-group-item">
                product 10
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="category5">
            <ul class="list-group products">
              <li class="list-group-item">
                product 11
              </li>
              <li class="list-group-item">
                product 12
              </li>
              <li class="list-group-item">
                product 13
              </li>
              <li class="list-group-item">
                product 14
              </li>
               <li class="list-group-item">
                product 15
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>             


<script>
$('ul.panel-collapse li').click(function (e) { 
    $('ul li.active').removeClass('active');
    e.preventDefault()
            .tab('show');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
</script>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c45zjz81/)

Comment: What part of your HTML is the "tab"? As you've explained it right now, you're not being very clear on what it is you're trying to do.

Comment: The a inside the li.list-group-item, I'm trying to solve this console error. everything works as I expected

Comment: Right, I see `.tab()` is part of bootstrap.

Comment: Please don't use only Fiddle links in your questions. Try adding code snippets in your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('ul.panel-collapse li').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('ul.panel-collapse li.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).children().tab('show').addClass('active');
});
```

`$('ul.panel-collapse li')` gets your `.list-group-items`.

`$(this).children().tab('show');` targets the bootstrap tag markup in the `a` children of your clicked `li`.

We can chain some methods on `$(this)` as long as those methods chained after it don't return something new. So I don't have to call `$(this)` twice for `$(this).addClass('active');`

Using `$(e.target)` from Peter's solution is better though as it gets the element that triggered the event directly.

Comment: I added $('a', this) before the .tab('show') and now It's working without errors.. Also your solution works well. TNX (;

Answer (score 0):

Try the following example

```js
$('ul.panel-collapse li').click(function (e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    $('ul li.active').removeClass('active');   
    $(e.target).tab('show').addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.badge {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container container-pad">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <ul class="list-group category" role="tablist">
          <li class="list-group-item">
            <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse"  href="#collapseOne">
              categories 1
            </a>
          </li>
          <ul id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <li class="list-group-item" role="presentation">
              <a href="#category1" aria-controls="category1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">category 1<span class="badge">1</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="list-group-item" role="presentation">
              <a href="#category2" aria-controls="category2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">category 2<span class="badge">2</span></a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <li class="list-group-item">
            <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse"  href="#collapseTwo">
              categories 2
            </a>
          </li>
          <ul id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <li class="list-group-item" role="presentation">
              <a href="#category3" aria-controls="category3" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">category 3<span class="badge">3</span></a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <li class="list-group-item">
            <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse"  href="#collapseThree">
              categories 3
            </a>
          </li>
          <ul id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <li class="list-group-item" role="presentation">
              <a href="#category4" aria-controls="category4" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">category 4<span class="badge">4</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="list-group-item" role="presentation">
              <a href="#category5" aria-controls="category5" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">category 5<span class="badge">5</span></a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-9">
        <div class="tab-content">
          <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="category1">
            <ul class="list-group products">
             <li class="list-group-item">
               product 1
             </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="category2">
            <ul class="list-group products">
              <li class="list-group-item">
                product 2
              </li>
              <li class="list-group-item">
               product 3
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="category3">
            <ul class="list-group products">
              <li class="list-group-item">
                product 4
              </li>
              <li class="list-group-item">
               product 5
              </li>
              <li class="list-group-item">
                product 6
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="category4">
            <ul class="list-group products">
              <li class="list-group-item">
                product 7
              </li>
              <li class="list-group-item">
                product 8
              </li>
              <li class="list-group-item">
                product 9
              </li>
              <li class="list-group-item">
                product 10
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="category5">
            <ul class="list-group products">
              <li class="list-group-item">
                product 11
              </li>
              <li class="list-group-item">
                product 12
              </li>
              <li class="list-group-item">
                product 13
              </li>
              <li class="list-group-item">
                product 14
              </li>
               <li class="list-group-item">
                product 15
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Updated [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3s5vgtct/1/)